# Axler Example 3.13

Tags: linear-algebra

As an example of the null space, Axler gives the following example:

> Suppose $\varphi \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{C}^3, \mathbf{F})$ is defined by $\varphi(z_1, z_2, z_3) = z_1 + 2z_2 + 3z_3$. Then $\text{null } \varphi = \{(z_1, z_2, z_3) \in \mathbf{C}^3 \colon z_1 + 2z_2 + 3z_3 = 0\}$. A basis of $\text{null } \varphi$ is $(-2,1,0), (-3,0,1)$.

There are a few things about this example I don't fully understand. By $\mathbb{C}^3$, I believe he's referring to three-tuples of complex numbers. He uses $\mathbf{F}$ to refer either to the real numbers or the complex numbers, but because the inputs are triples of complex numbers and the output a sum, I think almost surely $\mathbf{F}$ can only be $\mathbb{C}$, rather than either of the two. The definition of the kernel he writes down makes sense, but I don't understand the basis. These two triples have real values only, so I'm struggling to see how they could span a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^3$. It isn't clear either how he found these two vectors from the equation.

I'd appreciate any help in parsing this.

Comment: Real valued vectors can span a complex space when they're spanning over $\mathbb{C}$. E.g. $(1,0),(0,1)$ is a basis for $\mathbb{C}^2$ because if you want, say, the vector $(1+2i,3+4i)$ you can take it as the combination
$$(1+2i)(1,0)+(3+4i)(0,1)$$

Comment: I agree with you F must be a misprint for C

Comment: Here is how he found this basis:$ z_1 + 2z_2 + 3z_3 = 0\iff(z_1,z_2,z_3)=(-2z_2 -3z_3,z_2,z_3)\iff\exists\lambda,\mu\in\Bbb C,(z_1,z_2,z_3)=(-2\lambda-3\mu,\lambda,\mu)\iff (z_1,z_2,z_3)\in span ((-2,1,0),(3,0,1)).$

Comment: For all $z \in \bf C$, $z=\varphi(z,0,0) \in \bf F$; so ${\bf F}=\bf C$ is the only possibility.

Comment: Thank you for all the extremely helpful comments. This makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: Yes, that is a typo on my part. In that example, $\mathbf{F}$ should be $\mathbf{C}$. I have already made this correction in my LaTeX file for the fourth edition of Linear Algebra Done Right (publication expected around December 2023).